# Iterating through a vector for comparison in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to write a program where given a vector, you use iterators to compare the first and last number of the vector, then moves in and compares the next ones. I wrote the for loop to do that, but am unsure how to make it stop once they reach the center of the vector.

For the for loop I have:

```
for (a = v.begin(), b = v.rbegin(); a != v.end(), b != v.rend(); a++, b++)
```

where `a` is the forward iterator and `b` is a backwards iterator.
My assumption is that I need to change the condition of the for loop, but I'm unsure to what.

Comment: You mean some 'is_palindrome' function?

Comment: At the very least, you should change the condition to use `&&`.

Comment: Your loop condition `a!=v.end(), b!=v.rend()` uses the comma operator to execute both sub-expressions, but the result of the first (`a != v.end()`) will be thrown away and only the result of the second expression will be used. As for "reaching the center of the vector" it might make more sense to use *indexes* instead of iterators here. Then it would be easy to see if the indexes passes the "mid-point" of the vector length.

Comment: Your loop should work, even with *comma operator* instead of `&&`.

Comment: Why not `std::equal(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.rbegin())`? (From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal#Example) If you're not comparing for equality, you can search for some other high-order function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So bear in mind that `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a [random-access iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), which means that it has `operator<` defined.

Using this, and using the [`std::reverse_iterator<Iterator>::base()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) member function, we can rewrite your for-loop to the following:

```
auto a = v.begin();
auto b = v.rbegin();
for (; a < b.base(); ++a, ++b)
{
  // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to use `&&` and not the `,` operator in the comparison, which doesn't do what you think it does.

For your specific question you just keep going until both iterators reach each other, you can obtain the underlying `std::iterator` of a `std::reverse_iterator` through [`base()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base), eg:

```
template<typename T> bool isPalindrome(const std::vector<T>& data)
{
    for (auto it = data.begin(), it2 = data.rbegin(); it != data.end() && it2 != data.rend() && 
          it != it2.base(); ++it, ++it2)
        if (*it != *it2)
          return false;

    return true;
}
```